# Geocoder failed due to: REQUEST_DENIED google maps

Tags: javascript, html

There I have had this error when using Geocode I know there is a lot of the same question but I wasn't able to understand it so if you guys have a solution please give me your version of my code with your code inside of it

here is my code

```
           <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
            <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY" async defer></script>
```

Thank you I hope someone could help been having this problem alot

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2):

This error indicates on a missing Google Maps API key.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

> 1. Click the button below, to get an API key using the Google Cloud Platform Console. You will be asked to (1) pick one or more products, (2) select or create a project, and (3) set up a billing account. Once your API key is created you will be prompted to restrict the key's usage. For more information, see Restricting an API key.
>      (Button is present in the link)
> 2. When loading the Maps JavaScript API, substitute YOUR_API_KEY in the
>      code below with the API key you got from the previous step.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you follow the steps beyond the link, that should fix the error you're getting.